# Task in .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, multitasking

I'm trying to do parallel programming using Task in .Net 4.0 c#.

output of my program is little confusing.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Task> lstTasks =  new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(i.ToString()));
                lstTasks.Add(tsk);
            }

            Task.WaitAll(lstTasks.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DoSomething(string tasKname)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tasKname);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
```

Output is

```
5
5
5
5
5
Done.
```

I'm expecting.

```
0
1
2
3
4
Done.
```

where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is this duplicate?? I dont think so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a [closure](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) when you defined the function `() => DoSomething(i.ToString())`.

A closure is an anonymous function/lamdba that references some variables defined in the method where the closure was created. In your case, that's variable `i`.

When this function is executed, it will use the current value of `i`, not the value that `i` had when you created it.

You have to be aware that calling `Task.Factory.StartNew` will not start executing the task immediately. In your case, the tasks started executing after the `for` loop, so the value of `i` is 5.

To get the results you expect, use a separate variable in the loop to store the current value of `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int k = i;
    Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(k.ToString()));
    lstTasks.Add(tsk);
}
```

You shouldn't expect the results in any particular order though.

Comment: your solution is working fine....but I did not understand the concept which are trying to explain me..can you explain in detail.

Comment: @Manish I added some more explanation to my answer. I missed one important thing in the original answer - `Task.Factory.StartNew` will not start executing the task immediately.

Comment: What made you say that..the Task is not executed until the for loop is completed?

Comment: @Manish `StartNew` adds the task to thread pool queue and returns. Then the thread pool will assign the task to a thread. The thread will run when the OS schedules it to run. It all takes some time, enough to finish executing the `for` loop. You can test it by adding another `Console.Writeline()` after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing a variable that is changing within your loop.  Essentially, your `foreach` runs so quickly, by the time `DoSomething` runs, `i` is 5.  try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(i.ToString()));
    lstTasks.Add(tsk);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

and you should see your expected output in the console.

---

you say `I'm expecting 0 1 2 3 4`.  But you shouldn't.  The most important aspect of Tasks is you don't know when they'll complete.  For example, when I alter your code to use a Parallel.Foreach():

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 5), i =>
{
    Task tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(i.ToString()));
    lstTasks.Add(tsk);
});
```

I get the expected numbers, 0 through 4, but in a random order each time i run the code, because we are using `Tasks` that are all running independently of eachother.

Comment: you  are correct..any order of 0.4 is ok..but not 5.5.5.5.5

Comment: but I dont want to add sleep to the for loop.. @jakub method is working fine

Comment: I absolutely don't recommend sleeping in your code, it was a demonstration.  If your code is this simple, you don't need tasks at all.